# Update Field in Join table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select query as

```
SELECT MFD.MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER_ID
FROM MONTHLY_FUND_DETAIL MFD, MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER MFH
WHERE
    MFH.MONTH < TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate), 'MM')
    AND MFH.YEAR <= TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate), 'YYYY')
    AND MFH.CERTIFIED_DT IS NOT NULL
    AND MFD.SENT_TO_EXT_IND = 'N' AND MFH.COURT_CD = '56'
GROUP BY MFD.MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER_ID
```

Now I want an update query which will set `MFD.SENT_TO_EXT_IND` field to `'Y'` for above join

Please suggest the query.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are missing the full query. Where is the FROM clause?

Comment: I believe he wants it after select MFD.MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER_ID, while editing I noticed there was no FROM

Comment: Although some people have answered you on UPDATE query, you might as well learn about it & be an expert instead ;). I mean - writing an UPDATE is the basic thing to start with. You can get answers on SO, but you won't learn it unless you read/understand the stuff.

Comment: Presumably MFH.MONTH and MFH.YEAR are not a character type -- you have an implicit type conversion in the predictas on them that you ought to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The `update` clause works with a subquery in Oracle. So, you can do this:

```
UPDATE
(SELECT
    mfd.sent_to_ext_ind
FROM 
    MONTHLY_FUND_DETAIL MFD, 
    MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER MFH 
WHERE 
    (MFH.MONTH < TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate),'MM') 
    AND MFH.YEAR <=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate) , 'YYYY')) 
    AND MFH.CERTIFIED_DT IS NOT NULL 
    AND MFD.SENT_TO_EXT_IND = 'N' 
    AND MFH.COURT_CD= '56') mfd
 SET sent_to_ext_ind = 'Y'
```

Just make sure that the table you're updating is the first table in the `FROM` clause. You shouldn't have to modify your query to much.

It should be noted that this is not ANSI, but it does work with Oracle. Since you're using Oracle, you can take advantage of it!

Note that this doesn't actually have a join condition...there should be a `MFD.FUNDID = MFH.FUNDID` or similar clause in the `WHERE` condition. Otherwise, you are going a very roundabout way of setting all `N` values to `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query won't compile, since it misses `FROM` clause.

If we add it, we'll see that the query is a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT  MFD.MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER_ID
FROM    MONTHLY_FUND_DETAIL MFD, MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER MFH
WHERE   MFH.MONTH < TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate),'MM'
        AND MFH.YEAR <= TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate) , 'YYYY'))
        AND MFH.CERTIFIED_DT IS NOT NULL
        AND MFH.COURT_CD = '56'
        AND MFD.SENT_TO_EXT_IND = 'N'
GROUP BY
        MFD.MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER_ID
```

, so you are asking about updating all rows of `MONTHLY_FUND_DETAIL` that currently hold an 'N':

```
UPDATE  MONTHLY_FUND_DETAIL
SET     SENT_TO_EXT_IND = 'Y'
WHERE   SENT_TO_EXT_IND = 'N'
```

Not sure, though, that it's what you want.

Add a `JOIN` condition into your query so that it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following update statement

```
update MONTHLY_FUND_DETAIL 
set SENT_TO_EXT_IND  = 'Y'
where MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER_ID in (
SELECT MFD.MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER_ID
FROM MONTHLY_FUND_DETAIL MFD, MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER MFH
WHERE
    MFH.MONTH < TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate), 'MM')
    AND MFH.YEAR <= TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate), 'YYYY')
    AND MFH.CERTIFIED_DT IS NOT NULL
    AND MFD.SENT_TO_EXT_IND = 'N' AND MFH.COURT_CD = '56'
GROUP BY MFD.MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing "FROM" prior to MONTHLY_FUND_DETAIL on the first line.  If so, this is one way to perform the update that you're looking to do:

```
UPDATE MFDT
SET MFDT.SENT_TO_EXT_IND = 'Y'
FROM MONTHLY_FUND_DETAIL MFDT
JOIN MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER MFH ON MFDT.MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER_ID = MFH.MONTHLY_FUND_HEADER_ID
WHERE (MFH.MONTH < TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate),'MM') 
    AND MFH.YEAR <=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate) , 'YYYY')) 
    AND MFH.CERTIFIED_DT IS NOT NULL 
    AND MFD.SENT_TO_EXT_IND = 'N' 
    AND MFH.COURT_CD= '56'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
update
( select mfd.sent_to_ext_ind 
  from   monthly_fund_detail mfd, 
         monthly_fund_header mfh 
  where (mfh.month < to_char(trunc(sysdate),'MM') 
  and mfh.year <=to_char(trunc(sysdate) , 'YYYY')) 
  and mfh.certified_dt is not null 
  and mfd.sent_to_ext_ind = 'N' and mfh.court_cd= '56' 
)
set sent_to_ext_ind = 'Y';
```

Contrary to other answers, Oracle does **not** support "update from" syntax.

Comment: @Tony: no. To update a table in view (including an inline view) containing a `JOIN`, the table you are updating must be joined with another table on a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` field. This guarantees that each row from table you are updating will be selected at most once. If this condition is not satisified, `Oracle` will reject the query at compile time with infamous `ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table`. Oracle decided to make it a compile time restriction, not runtime, that's why your query will fail with this error.

Comment: @Tony: the view the `@op` provided does not contain any jon condition at all.

Comment: Oh I see.  I must admit I had assumed without checking that the necessary joins were there!